# ros process in subsumption architecture

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

Can anyone know how to run ROS process in subsumption architecture sytle, with which, different node have different priorities and some nodes can be triggered/terminate by a topic message.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172499/ros-process-in-subsumption-architecture/) by [Rikardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5410/rikardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to combine some multiplexers, for manual switching by an actual call: http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux, for priority based switching http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux (Only for cmd_vel, but should be easily adaptable).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on 2015-09-19**:
Can multiplexer construct a subsumption architecture on ROS?